# How to properly include a license file within an EPUB?

Tags: license-notice, font

I am currently working on an EPUB project in which I'll embed a font licensed under OFL.

According to the [second point in the **PERMISSION & CONDITIONS** section](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/ofl-1.1/), the font "*may be bundled* (...) *provided that each copy contains the above copyright notice **and this license***".

There is no problem to include the "copyright notice", which can be easily integrated into `title-page` or `colophon` XHTML files, but what about the license `.txt` file itself? What is the better way to include this kind of file within an EPUB structure?

Comment: Any reason why you can't just put it in an appendix in the back of the book? If you're worried about it not being seen, put a notice on the copyright page saying, "This work includes fonts under the SIL Open Font License 1.1. See the appendix for the license text."

Comment: Not a particular reason not to put it as an appendix right now. I am looking for possibilities to include this file as properly as possible. I consider that your suggestion is a possible option indeed.

Answer (score 4):

I'd add an appendix to the book with the relevant license text copied there. As far as I understand, there's no restriction on what format you redistribute the license by.

Answer (score 2):

First, thank to [apsillers](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/users/50/apsillers) for the comment and [Mureinik](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/users/327/mureinik) for the answer. They have substantially helped me to find a suitable manner to integrate the license into the `.epub` file.

As there is no type for `appendix` (and no one for `license` too) in the [OPF guide specifications](http://www.idpf.org/epub/20/spec/OPF_2.0.1_draft.htm#Section2.6), I have finally opted to use the `copyright-page` guide element to create the `ofl.xhtml` file, such as :

```
<reference type="copyright-page" title="Copyright page" href="Text/ofl.xhtml"/>
```

In the `title.xhtml`, I have formatted a link in the notice this way:

```
<a href="../Text/ofl.xhtml">Open Font License 1.1</a></p>
```

By the way, I have found another question ([Where should font licenses be embedded?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/6485/6569)) related to this problem, but the suggested implementations cause error when checking the file with [Sigil](https://github.com/Sigil-Ebook/Sigil) and [FlightCrew](https://github.com/Sigil-Ebook/flightcrew):

> Error XML child not recognized: the `<licence>` element is not an allowed child of the `<metadata>` element

So, *at this time*, it appears that the solution of a kind of appendix (a copyright page in this case) seems to be appropriate.